# how to apply a fraction of rotation

Tags: java, apache, math

I'm using an apache math library. I want to apply a rotation (to a vector) that is proportional to rotation that I have at hand. Something like

```
Rotation rotation2 = number * rotation1;
return rotation2.applyTo(vector);
```

where number is the multiplier for the rotation angle, and number == 1 would result in rotation2 being equal to rotation1, and number == 0 would result to no rotation (rotation angle == 0)

How can I do this?

Comment: you should get a quaternion out of `Rotation` and then perform a spherical linear interpolation (SLERP). Then put the quaternion back in `Rotation`. I'm not familiar with apache math lib, but almost all math engines use quaternions for rotations.

Comment: Cross reference: in case you are interested not only in rotations, but general affine transformations, then [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/614807/35416) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like rashmatash suggested in his comment, you should

1. Extract the quaternion components from the [`Rotation`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/threed/Rotation.html) using [`getQ0`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/threed/Rotation.html#getQ0%28%29) through [`getQ3`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/threed/Rotation.html#getQ3%28%29).
2. Get the angle of rotation using [`getAngle`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/threed/Rotation.html#getAngle%28%29).
3. Perform a [SLERP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) computation.
4. Turn the result back into a `Rotation`.

Something like this (untested):

```
double angle = rotation1.getAngle();
double sinAngle = Math.sin(angle);
double factor = Math.sin(number * angle) / sinAngle;
double factor2 = Math.sin((1 - number) * angle) / sinAngle;
double q0 = factor * rotation1.getQ0() + factor2;
double q1 = factor * rotation1.getQ1();
double q2 = factor * rotation1.getQ2();
double q3 = factor * rotation1.getQ3();
Rotation rotation2 = new Rotation(q0, q1, q2, q3, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can getAxis() and getAngle() for the rotation, then build another rotation with the same axis and modified angle. That is easier than working with quaternions.